# Is it possible to run a MAAS Server in a VM, but to have mixed VM nodes and physical nodes in the cluster?

Tags: maas

I have a working physical MAAS server and 3 nodes - (2 bare metal and 1 node that's housing a bunch of VM nodes), I'd like to host the VM nodes on the same MAAS server physical machine, effectively giving me 3 bare metal nodes + a bunch of VM nodes sitting on MAAS server.

How do I go about this? My /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.26.0.158
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 172.26.0.1
dns_nameservers 10.1.1.100 192.168.3.3 172.26.0.253

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.1.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Would creating a simple linux bridge on eth1 work? eth1 is currently serving MAAS DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can go about this. Let call the node that is destined to host the VMs the "infra" node.

Create all VMs on the infra node. MAAS will also be deployed as a vm. 
For this all you need to do is to create bridges on the infra node and connect the VMs directly. Just make sure that DHCP is off on the network that MAAS will use to PXE boot other nodes.

If you want to setup MAAS directly on the infra node. You can create a bridge (br0) and in the MAAS cluster configuration use br0 as the interface for the network.